# Magento 2.3: Sort Product Attribute Set Groups in Admin

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-edit

I'm trying to clean up our product forms in the admin using Attribute Set groups, however, sorting them in the Attribute Set options doesn't seem to affect the product edit page:

[image]
[image]

As you can see in this example, Firmware group should come after the Images group, however that's not the case on the actual product page.

I've tried clearing cache and re-indexing. Any other ways to sort these, possibly via a layout file?

Answer (score 0):

Through this method
`\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup::addAttributeGroup`

it is understood that the groups have a sort order.

**Below is the table that contains them**

[image]

Through the repository you can modify its sortOrder:

```
\Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\GroupRepository
```

Cheers